# Import Razor @helper from Class Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-2

Is there a way to import a dll from a class project (or maybe another web application project) into a web application project and reuse a @helper? The reusability for web applications with Razor seems pretty much zero if that cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but you have to jump through several hoops.

1. You need to obtain [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/): "This is a Custom Tool for Visual Studio that allows processing Razor files at design time instead of runtime, allowing them to be built into an assembly for simpler reuse and distribution. "
2. Using RazorGenerator, you can create .cshtml files in your class library project that declare `helper` functions.  For example, in a file called Foo.cshtml:

   ```
   @helper MyHelper(string parameter) {<text>@parameter</text>}
   ```
3. These helpers will exist as static methods in the static class representing your .cshtml file.  In the above example, that would translate to `Foo.MyHelper`.
4. You can invoke these static methods from your web application's .cshtml file just like any other static method.  (assuming you've added the correct `using` directives to point to the namespace containing your helper.)  For example:

   ```
   <div>@Foo.MyHelper("hello world")</div>
   ```

Comment: Sorry for not answering but now I had time to try it out.It works like a charm! Thank you for your great help!